# how to browse files in a folder?

Tags: c, file, directory

i'm trying to browse the files in a folder to compute some figures, and I ran into some trouble trying to do so. I'm working with Code::Blocks, and writing in C. I've looked at similar questions & answers on this website, but none seemed to adress my issues.

here's how my code begins :

```
#include
<dirent.h>

#define prod

#ifndef prod
#define DIRPATH "C:\\Users\\User1\\...etc
#define FILEPATH "C:\\Users\\User1\\..   \\"
#else
#define DIRPATH  "C:\\Users\\User2\\..etc
#define FILEPATH C:\\Users\\User2\\..    \\"

#endif

int main(){

DIR* dir = NULL;
struct dirent *currentFile = NULL;
dir = opendir(DIRPATH);
char path[100] = FILEPATH;

while((currentFile = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
  if(strcmp(currentFile->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentFile->d_name, "..") != 0)
  {
      char *filePath = (char *) malloc((strlen(path) + strlen(currentFile->d_name) - 1) * sizeof(char));
      filePath= strcpy(filePath, path);
      strcat(filePath,currentFile->d_name);
      FILE *file = fopen(filePath,"r");
      // PROGRAM DIES AT THIS POINT //
      free(filePath);
      fclose(file);
// the rest runs just fine
   }
}
```

By using printf, I was able to deduce that my program crashes when it's supposed to fopen the file, although I don't understand why. I've printed filePath, and it gives me what it's supposed to. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is ?

Thanks a lot,
Nicolas

Comment: `(strlen(path) + strlen(currentFile->d_name) - 1)` : `- 1` --> `+ 1`

Comment: my comment may not be clear enough, i'll edit it. It dies when it should open the file, and if I print filePath just before the fopen line, it gives me exactly what I want (that is to say, C:\\Users\\.. file.txt)

Comment: oh god I can't believe i've been missing such an obvious error -_- thank you bluepixy, case solved!

Comment: Your code does not compile -- most likely because of the malformed `#define`s? Make sure you post *relevant*, *actual* code.